# Rails Many to many relationships with connecting or cloning two table with references?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord, has-many-through, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm a new with Rails and I'm having trouble with some types of associations that seem a bit more complex than the ones I've been exposed to so far.

```
Zombie_users      Body_parts_status                              Body_parts

| id | name |     | id | user_id | body_part_id | recovery |     | id | name     |
|-----------| --> |----------------------------------------| --> |---------------|
| 1  | Joe  |     | 1 |    1     |     2        |   10%    |     | 1  | left leg |
| 2  | Max  |     | 2 |    1     |     3        |   43%    |     | 2  | brain    |
                                                                 | 3  | hair     |
                                                                 | 4  | blue eye |


Zobmie_users    Recovery_tools          Body_parts_impacts

| id | name |   | id |user_id| name |   | id|recovery_tool_id| body_part_id | impact |
|-----------|-->|-------------------|-->|--------------------------------------------|
| 1  | Joe  |   | 1  |   1   |hammer|   | 1 |       1        |      2       |   10%  |
| 2  | Max  |   | 2  |   1   |magic |   | 2 |       2        |      3       |   43%  |
```

[graphic illustration of the needed functionality](https://gomockingbird.com/projects/awkdgjk)

We have **users** and a list of **body parts**.
I need that the users will be able to create **recovery tools** with which they can through **Body Parts impact** recover their **body parts status** :)
and be able to check what part of the body still need to be fixed(compared to the list) and what body parts they have already corrected.

My problem is that I do not know how to implement such connections.
because I need to have some kind of clone of the **body parts** to **body parts status** for each user.
But how I reference it so it also works with **Body Parts impacts**
I do not have even a concept of where to start :)

**body parts** table is just a long listing of all the parts of the human body
and each user should have their own "copy" of all these parts.

Comment: There are several problems to be solved here. You might want to break this up into smaller questions.

Comment: Thank you @ahmacleod this is good advice, the only complexity of formulating the questions :)